# Persistent Error with LibGDX Freetype Font?

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx, freetype

```
The library 'gdx-freetype-natives.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2014-03-09 01:54:37 - MyGame-android] The following libraries were found:
[2014-03-09 01:54:37 - MyGame-android]  - libgdx-freetype.so
[2014-03-09 01:54:37 - MyGame-android]  - libgdx-freetype64.so
```

I've researched this problem, and tried to fix it. Many people have been told that removing the "gdx-freetype-natives.jar" from the android project library folder and from the exports list will help, but it isn't helping me. I've removed the native jar from the android folder and the export, yet the same thing keeps happening. Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Try again and follow this instruction: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype I just checked it an it does work. Maybe dont take the nightly this sometimes causes troubles.

Comment: What type of device? If it is the emulator then what CPU type did you pick?